# The update and upgrade of Debian ask me to insert a CD

Tags: debian, repository

The update and upgrade of Debian ask me to insert a CD.

This is the content of my /etc/apt/source.list

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS                    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

###### Debian Main Repos 
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

This is the output of the execution of the `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch InRelease
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch InRelease
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch Release 
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch Release
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch Release
Hit:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Hit:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Hit:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Hit:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Hit:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Hit:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Hit:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Hit:24 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:25 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Hit:26 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:27 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Hit:28 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:29 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Hit:30 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Hit:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:25 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:29 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:24 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:26 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign:28 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:30 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-3 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09] stretch/contrib Translation-en
```

**Why is asking to insert a cdrom if I am fetching a German repository?**

If I try to install a .deb file I receive the following output:

> Media change: please insert the disc labeled  'Debian GNU/Linux 9.2.1
>   *Stretch* - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20171013-13:09'

Comment: what is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? and please remove those blank lines from the output listing.

Comment: The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty

Comment: I notice you refer it to it as `source.list`. I just wanted to make sure that you are actually referring to `sources.list`, right? What other files do you have in `/etc/apt`?

Comment: Welcome, your question is unclear , please add the output of `ls /etc/apt/` , as said in the @Gaurav comment.

Answer (score 2):

Double check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for lines that contain `cdrom:`. Ensure they are all commented out. Then run `apt update`.

Comment: The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty